# Pass text in greater than sign and less than sign to the backend

Tags: java, spring, jsp, xss

I want user to be able to pass value like "here is (greater-than sign)some(less-than sign) text" to the backend of my spring application.

Some mechanism (I haven't investigate it yet) cuts off greater-than sign and less-than sign and everything that's inside it while passing form to the controller. I know I could probably disable it in some filter but instead of forcing it, I would rather understand why it's done. I am looking around but cannot find anything useful. I would appreciate any helpful links.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried character literals ?

What we call it as "Escape characters in  Java".

Escape Sequences. A character preceded by a backslash () is an escape sequence and has a special meaning to the compiler.

Comment: I tried to play around htmlEscape flag in JSP but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the unknown mechanism is removing not just the "< >" characters but also "everything that's inside" them, this mechanism is most likely guarding against [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacks.

An XSS attack could occur if user input includes unsafe strings which could be interpreted as HTML when sent back to the browser.  For example, on an INPUT field expecting a "name", imagine instead of entering a name a malicious user types in:

```
<script>some_malicious_code()</script>
```

Subsequently, pages displaying this "name" field to different users would include the malicious code instead.

So care must be taken before removing whatever mechanism that's providing you XSS protection, to ensure that an equivalent level of safety remains.